# Markov Chains - Can we set the Initial distribution as $X_{1}$ instead of $X_{0}$ to calculate a non-conditional probability?

Tags: markov-process

Had a small question when I was going through Ross – Probability Models. Given a discrete-time Markov chain
$\{X_{n}: n=1,2,3 \ldots\}$ with a state space $\mathcal{S} = \{0,1\}$, and an initial distribution $P(X_{0} = 0) = \alpha = 1 - P(X_{0} = 1)$, we can write the unconditional distribution of $X_{n}$ as:

$P(X_{n} = k) = \sum_{i\in \mathcal{s}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{0} = i)P(X_{0} = i)$

Assuming we calculate the distribution of $X_{1}$ from a given transition probability matrix and the given distribution of $X_{0}$, can we write:

$P(X_{n+1} = k) = \sum_{i\in \mathcal{s}} P(X_{n+1} = k | X_{1} = i)P(X_{1} = i)$.

Here, all I do is change the initial distribution from $X_{0}$ to $X_{1}$. Is this allowed?

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  For a first-order Markov process you need to condition on $X_{n-1}$ not $X_0$.  You condition on $X_0$ only when considering the probability distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the "unconditional" probability of $X_{n}$ for a discrete-time Markov chain. All unconditional probabilities are computed by conditioning on the initial distribution which is $X_{0}$ instead of $X_{n-1}$ (which would be the case if I am computing $P(X_{n} = k | X_{n-1} = j)$ instead of the unconditional $P(X_{n} = k)$).

Comment: Unconditional probabilities from a Markov model are state occupancy probabilities.  They are computed using recursive matrix multiplications, each element of which conditions on the _most recent_ value of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes—what you've stumbled upon is a case of variable elimination. You might as well change the $n+1$s to $n$, just to reduce clutter:

$$
P(X_{n} = k) = \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{1} = i)P(X_{1} = i)
\text{.}
$$

---

#### Short proof:

$$
\begin{align}
P(X_{n} = k) &= \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{1} = i)P(X_{1} = i) & \text{Your starting point} \\
P(X_{n} = k) &= \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{1} = i) \sum_{j \in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{1} = i \mid X_{0} = j) P(X_0 = j) & \text{Definition of } P(X_1) \text{ from Ross}\\
P(X_{n} = k) &= \sum_{j \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{1} = i)  P(X_{1} = i \mid X_{0} = j) P(X_0 = j) & \text{Push constant inside second summation}\\
P(X_{n} = k) &= \sum_{j \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{1} = i, X_{0}=j)  P(X_{1} = i \mid X_{0} = j) P(X_0 = j) & \text{Markov assumption}\\
P(X_{n} = k) &= \sum_{j \in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k \mid X_{0} = j) P(X_0 = j) & \text{Definition of marginal probability}\\
\end{align}
$$

#### Some discussion:

You've provided the following formula from the Ross book. The formula is correct, but it's one of those 'Why would you ever write it this way?' things.

$$P(X_{n} = k) = \sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} P(X_{n} = k | X_{0} = i)P(X_{0} = i)$$

All of the fun of the Markov chain is in this term: $P(X_{n} = k | X_{0} = i)$, which we tend to decompose with the chain rule and the Markov conditional independence assumption: $P(x_n | x_0) = \sum_{x_{n-1}} \cdots \sum_{x_1} P(x_n | x_{n-1}) \ldots P(x_1 | x_0)$. Usually we'll write it explicitly. But Ross's equation is still correct.

Comment: What you've described is not a Markov model.   You have described an "observe a sequence of events and forget all but the first two" model.  Unconditional probabilities for a Markov model must involve $n-1$ multiplications, not 2 multiplications.

Comment: The intermediate states have been marginalized out in the given formula. The multiplications are present in computing $P(X_n \mid X_0)$.

Comment: I need to ponder this. Something about the model assumptions you are making just doesn't feel right but it may be my fault.  In the literature this has been treated as a missing data problem so I can't see why it's this easy.

Comment: I’m happy to discuss further—or to be proven wrong. My assumption is that $P(x_n | x_0)$ is computed by the Markov assumption and by marginalizing out the intermediate states. $P(x_n | x_0) = \sum_{x_{n-1}} \cdots \sum_{x_1} P(x_n | x_{n-1}) \ldots P(x_1 | x_0)$

Comment: @FrankHarrell Did we come to a consensus here?

Comment: Yes I think so.  It would help me to see this: For a known initial state and missing states at $t=3$ and $t=5$ what is the joint likelihood for states 1, 2, 4, 6 under a first-order Markov assumptions, and how might we recognize per-observation likelihood components.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion holds even if you drop the assumption that $X_n$ is a Markov chain. In general, if $Y$ and $Z$ are any two random variables both having state space $\{0, 1\}$, then by the second version of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement) given by Wikipedia,

$$
P(Z = k) = P(Z = k | Y = 0)P(Y=0) + P(Z = k | Y = 1)P(Y=1)
$$

Comment: This makes me wonder about the general approach for constructing likelihood function components for such partial information.  When the previous state is known the likelihood contribution is very simple once you specify the transition model.  How does one think about likelihood components when you can only do partial conditioning?